# Cannot invoke function with an argument list of type in Swift Test class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, testing, xctest

I am attempting to write a test as shown below, but I receive the following compiler error => Cannot invoke 'include' with an argument list of type '([User], userId: String)'.

```
func testInclude() {
    var users = mockUsers()
    XCTAssert(self.viewController.include(users, userId: "2"), "Pass")
}
```

The mockUsers function is as shown below.

```
func mockUsers() -> [User]{
    var users = [User(userId: "1", username: "soupguy", gender: 0, name: "Bob"),
        User(userId: "2", username: "breadeater", gender: 1, name: "Alice"),
        User(userId: "3", username: "lawnmowersrule", gender: 0, name: "Alex")]
    return users
}
```

The include function that is being tested is shown below.

```
public func include(array: [User], userId: String) -> Bool {
    for item in array {
        if item.userId == userId {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I have tried changing types and storing the results in temporary variables, but have had no success in getting the test to compile.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that one of your 'func' are wrong, go back and check all of you functions and cleaning your project form product tab on the Xcode menu bar might help as well.